# Visual basic 10.0 does not support async methods or lambdas

Tags: vb.net, async-await, .net-4.0

In a new project AspNet WebForms with VB targeting .NET 4.0 I got this error:

> Visual basic 10.0 does not support async methods or lambdas

The code is this:

```
<WebMethod>
Public Shared Async Function MethodNameAsync() As Task(Of String)
    Dim res As String = ""

    Try

        Dim succ = False
        Dim taskRes = Await TaskEx.Run(Async Function()
                                           Await TaskEx.Delay(10000)
                                           succ = True
                                           res = "OK"
                                           Return res
                                       End Function).ConfigureAwait(False)
        Return taskRes
    Catch ex As Exception
        res = "ERROR"
        Throw ex
    End Try

    Return res
End Function
```

Comment: `Async`/`Await` isn't natively supported in VB 10.0, so I assume you've installed [this](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2011/04/11/wccsp_async-ctp.aspx?m=1) or [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bclteam/2013/04/17/microsoft-bcl-async-is-now-stable/)? I don't know the reason why this code was generated, but I doubt there is a fix/workaround for something that is just a test feature. You might have to remove that code (if possible) or use a newer VS version.

Comment: Since you didn't mention, I have to ask: Do you _have_ to use VB10/.NET 4.0 or are you willing to upgrade to newer versions?

Comment: @VisualVincent im using VS 2017 and the project is a Web Application Web Forms with the framework .NET 4.0.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed yes i have to use that, im working on a project with that framework version and VB so i don't know how to get the feature of async methods, i had installed microsoft.bcl.async for use Task -> TaskEx.

Comment: Was this project created in an older version of VS?

Comment: @jmcilhinney no, is just a new project as a test i don't know why im getting this error

Answer (score 0):

Install the library Microsoft.Bcl from Nuget (`Install-Package Microsoft.Bcl`). It gets you async/await support as well as some other stuff only found in later framework versions.

It also lets you convert a previous-style async method (.BeginAsyncMethod -> .EndAsyncMethod) to an awaitable Task by using Task.Factory.FromAsync.

Have fun with your new async features in an old environment!